# Marking iterations on Cobweb / Staircase diagrams

Tags: numerical-methods, graphing-functions

In the below cobweb diagram I am interested in why the iterations $( x_1,x_2,x_3)$ are marked when the 'cobweb' intersects the line $y=x$.

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiYST.png

For example, why does the 'cobweb' not go up to the point on $y=g(x)$ to get $x_3$? 
Is there any special reason for this or is it just convention?

I've tried looking on Wolfram MathWorld, various PowerPoints and .pdfs available online, and Wikipedia, yet non have an explanation (or even add these points).

Comment: Your question is not very clear.  Could you go into more detail about which part of the diagram you are asking about?  Which part of it are you calling the 'cobweb'?  What do you suggest it should look like instead?  What do you mean by "go up to the point on $y = g(x)$ to get $x_3$"?